# Proof using the Contraction Mapping Theorem

Tags: numerical-methods

How do you identify an interval [f,g] so that the Contraction Mapping Theorem guarantees convergence to the positive fixed point for the following:

a) $\frac{14-x^3}{13}\ $
b) $e^{-x}$

I tried drawing a graph and i see it visually but am not so sure about proving it rigorously.

Comment: I believe this helps : find an interval (a,b) where $0<f^{'}(x) < \theta,  x \in (a,b)$ ($\theta$ is a fixed number between zero and one.) If you find this interval, you will have a root in this interval. try to do the some for the item b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Let $f(x) = \frac{14 - x^3}{13}$, then $|f'(x)| < 1 \iff |-3x^2/13| < 1 \iff x \in (-\sqrt{13/3}, \sqrt{13/3}).$

b) Similiarly, let $g(x) = e^{-x}$, then $|g'(x)| < 1 \iff |e^{-x}| < 1 \iff x  \in (0, \infty).$

Comment: You type faster than me

Comment: @recursiverecursion, really? I actually took my time on WolfamAlpha to make sure I didn't do any dumb calculation mistakes.

Comment: Well I am pretty bad with latex, just never got the hang of it.

Comment: Don't worry keep practicing.